# Realtime Executor Pool for Queue and Worker design

Tags: java, multithreading, amazon-web-services, message-queue

Rightnow, I'm trying to implement a queue-workers based design, where we receive millions of messages in queue. And workers are limited, so I'm using the following code assign work to workers. I'm using ExecutorService for the same:

```
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(POOL_SIZE); 

    while(LISTEN_FOR_MESSAGE_FLAG == true){
      Message receivedMessage = sqsClient.receiveMessage(request);

      if(receivedMessage == null){
        Thread.sleep(5000); // sleep for 5 seconds
      }
      else {
        // lock the message for a certain amount of time (60 secs). 
        // Other workers can't receive a message, when it is locked.
        sqsClient.changeMessageVisibility(receivedMessage, 60); 

        pool.execute(new Task(receivedMessage); // process the message.
      }
    }
```

I'm currently using Amazon SQS for the queue. Above code has serious problem. It receives the messages every 5 seconds and lock them with a visibility timeout. This lock will be broken once the visibility timeout is gone. Which causes workers to hold messages which are NOT LOCKED anymore. Therefore, it has problems of duplicate processing. 
Note: Amazon SQS provides a way to extend the visibility timeout.

Please help, how can above code be written to handle this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change

```
pool.execute(new Task(receivedMessage);
```

to :

```
Future<?> task = pool.submit(new Task(receivedMessage));
```

you can execute a helper task that extends the visibility time before time runs out. The helper task basically does a get() on the Future with a timeout shorter than the 60 seconds lock. and when a TimeoutException occurs, it extends the visibility timeout, and starts waiting on the Future again.

```
pool.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        boolean done = false;
        while (!done) {
            try {
                task.get(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                done = true;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                done = true;
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                done = true;
                // handle e.getCause()
            } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                // we need more time
                sqsClient.changeMessageVisibility(receivedMessage, 60);
            }
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks. How is your code going to control the inflow on messages? Because I don't want to pull new tasks from the queue, if the workers are already busy working on other tasks.

Comment: You could use a `Semaphore` holding permits equal to the number of workers. Before pulling a new message the main loop acquires a permission from the `Semaphore`. The task that monitors timely completion, can release the permit again when the task it monitors is done. In fact, this way you can probably do away with the 5 seconds of sleep.